# How to implement multiple aggregations using pandas groupby, referencing a specific column

Tags: pandas

I have data in a pandas data frame, and need to aggregate it. I need to do different aggregations across different columns similar to the below.

```
 group   min(rank)  min(rank)   min   sum

title   t_no       t_descr     rank    stores
A       1          a           1       1000
B       1          a           1       1000
B       2          b           2       800
C       2          b           2       800
D       1          a           1       1000
D       2          b           2       800
F       4          d           4       500
E       3          c           3       700
```

to:

```
title   t_no       t_descr     rank    stores
A       1          a           1       1000
B       1          a           1       1800
C       2          b           2       800
D       1          a           1       1800
E       3          c           3       700
F       4          d           4       500
```

You'll notice that title B and D have been aggregated, keeping the t_no & t_descr that corresponded to the minimum of the rank for the respective title group, while stores are summed. t_no & t_descr are just arbitrary text. I need the top rank by title, sum the stores, and keep the corresponding t_no & t_descr.

How can I do this within a single pandas groupby? This is dummy data; the real problem that I'm working on has many more aggregations, and I'd prefer not to have to do each aggregation individually, which I know how to do.

I started with the below, but realized that I really need the mins & maxs for t_no & t_descr to be based on rank col of the subgroup, not the columns themselves.

```
aggs = {
'rank': 'min',  
't_no': 'min',    # need t_no for row that is min(rank) by title.
't_descr': 'min'  # need t_descr for row that is min(rank) by title.
}

df2.groupby('title').agg(aggs).reset_index()
```

Perhaps there's a way to do this with a lambda? I'm sure there's a straightforward way to do this. And if groupby isn't the right method I'm obviously open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer that was similar to your attempt, but then realized you're trying to do something different.  It would be helpful if you changed the alphabetical order of your `t_descr` to show an example of where that column is based on another column's min, not it's own min.

Comment: hey @pshep123 thanks for the comment! I updated the example a bit. To explain, t_no and t_descr are just random text fields. I need to keep the field that correlates to the min of the rank column by title.

Comment: Change the `t_descr` in either B or D to reverse alphabetical order and your example will highlight that need. Currently code where the min of `t_descr` is found would yield the desired result despite using incorrect logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two step process...
aggregate for sum of stores and `idxmin` for `rank`...
then use `idxmin` to slice original dataframe and join it with the aggregate

```
agged = df.groupby('title').agg(dict(rank='idxmin', stores='sum'))
df.loc[agged['rank'], ['title', 't_no', 't_descr', 'rank']].join(agged.stores, on='title')

  title  t_no t_descr  rank  stores
0     A     1       a     1    1000
1     B     1       a     1    1800
3     C     2       b     2     800
4     D     1       a     1    1800
7     E     3       c     3     700
6     F     4       d     4     500
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what i needed. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different approach from @piRSquared, but gets you to the same spot:

**Code:**

```
# Set min and sum functions according to columns and generate new dataframe
f = {'rank':min, 'rank':min, 'stores':sum}
grouped = df.groupby('title').agg(f).reset_index()

# Then merge with original dataframe (keeping only the merged and new columns)
pd.merge(grouped, df[['title','rank','t_no','t_descr']], on=['title','rank'])
```

**Output:**

```
  title  stores  rank  t_no t_descr
0     A    1000     1     1       a
1     B    1800     1     1       a
2     C     800     2     2       b
3     D    1800     1     1       a
4     E     700     3     3       c
5     F     500     4     4       d
```

Of course you can organize the columns as you see fit.

Comment: Really appreciate the help, but this solution doesn't work for me- @piRsquared's answer is what i need. Thanks!